# Callbacks and Async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson-conversation, watson

How can I integrate Discovery with Conversation? I'm using NodeJS, but having problems because I want the conversation results to come *after* querying my data collection. I'm trying to use callbacks but no luck yet. I could use async, but could I use simple callbacks in this case? Help appreciated, thanks!

```
    function updateMessage(res, data) {
  if (!data.output) {
    data.output = {};
  } else {
    /* THIS CODE RETURNS CONVERSATION DATA FIRST, CAUSING THE DISCOVERY QUERY
    TO BECOME UNDEFINED */
    if (data.context.callDiscovery === true) {
      //Query collection
      Discovery.query(params, function(error, results) {
        data.output.text = "Getting what you need";

        //Set output graph card
        data.output.graph = {
          title: results.title,
          url: result.url,
          description: results.passage_text
        };

        return results;
      });
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're returning data outside of the query function, so the callback doesn't get executed as you already exited the function scope?

Comment: I apologize @linasmnew. I included the full function now. It needs to return outside the scope in case the data returned doesn't have a specified data.output

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing sync and async operations.

Here is an example of a function returning synchronously:

```
function (options) {
  if (options.flag) {
    return "Flag is set";
  } else {
    return "Flag is not set";
  }
}
```

This is an example of a function returning asynchronously:

```
function (options, done) {
  Discovery.query({options}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    return done(null, results);
  });
}
```

However, it's not recommended to return a function accepting callback immediately based on a condition or perform an async operation and then return. If your function does not take a callback in and does not call that callback when the async operation is finished, your function will be done executing before the async operations is finished. For example:

```
function mixedUp(options) {
  Discovery.query({options}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) return err;
    return results;
  });
  return 'default value';
}
```

This will always return default value, because before the Discovery request is finished, your function has returned.

You should make your function accept a callback or a done parameter, which in idiomatic node, is the last argument of your function. `function (options, moreOptions, done/callback/cb)` should be signature of your function. Then, your function should call that callback function when you want to perform an action.

```
function updateMessage(res, data, done) {
  if (!data.output) {
    data.output = {};
    return done(null, data);
  } else {
    /* THIS CODE RETURNS CONVERSATION DATA FIRST, CAUSING THE DISCOVERY QUERY
    TO BECOME UNDEFINED */
    if (data.context.callDiscovery === true) {
      //Query collection
      Discovery.query(params, function(error, results) {
        data.output.text = "Getting what you need";

        //Set output graph card
        data.output.graph = {
          title: results.title,
          url: result.url,
          description: results.passage_text
        };

        return done(null, results);
      });
    } else {
      return done(null, data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank yuo very much for your detailed explanations. You helped me understand callbacks much better. However, when I added your suggestions, I got `done is not defined`. Why is this?

Comment: Sure, I'm glad it was helpful for you. When you call the function, e.g. updateMessage(res, data) - you need to provide a callback function to it which will define done. e.g. `updateMessage(res, data, function (err, res) {console.log(err, res)});` this will have done defined during the execution of the callee and caller will get the results when done is called.